# How to pass a parameter value from main.py to a module

Tags: python

I have a main.py file that performs various data analysis steps using numerous classes imported from one module.  I have a certain hardcoded parameter in a method in one of the classes that I just want to define at the top of the main.py script.  I realize that I can define this separately in a config file and import into the module.

However, is there a way to just keep this in main.py without passing it as an argument to the method when I call it in main.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your secondary module.

```
from main import VARIABLE_NAME
...
if VARIABLE_NAME:
    pass
```